# Node hierarchy and inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I made a scene graph hierarchy where each node has a parent and possibly children. I created this BaseNode class

```
class BaseNode
{
public:
    BaseNode(const char *nodeName, BaseNode *parent);
    ~BaseNode();

    BaseNode* addChildSceneNode(const char *name);
    void deleteChildSceneNode(const char *name);
    void deleteAllChildSceneNodes();

    BaseNode* findFirstSceneNode(const char *name);
    BaseNode* getChildSceneNode(const char *name);
    BaseNode* getChildSceneNode(unsigned int index);

    void setName(const char *name);
    void setTranformation(const glm::mat4 &transformation);

    unsigned int getNumChildren() const { return _children.size(); }
    const char *name() const { return _name.c_str(); }
    BaseNode* parent() const { return _parent; }
    const glm::mat4& transformation() const { return _transformation; }
    const glm::mat4& toRootTransformation() const { return _toRoot; }

protected:
    std::string _name;

    glm::mat4 _transformation;
    glm::mat4 _toRoot;

    BaseNode *_parent;
    std::vector<BaseNode*> _children;
};
```

and I have this SceneNode class that inherits from BaseNode

```
class SceneNode : public BaseNode
{
public:
    SceneNode(const char *nodeName, SceneNode *parent);
    ~SceneNode();

    void attachRenderMeshData(RenderMeshData *renderMeshData);

    const std::vector<RenderMeshData*>* renderMeshDatas() { return &_meshDatas; }

private:
    std::vector<RenderMeshData*> _meshDatas;
};
```

Now my question is about all the member functions that include a BaseNode* parameter.

At the moment, when working with SceneNode objects, I have to explicitly cast BaseNode* to SceneNode* as follows

```
SceneNode *mySceneNode = new SceneNode("root", nullptr);
mySceneNode->addChildSceneNode("my child");
SceneNode *child = reinterpret_cast<SceneNode*>(mySceneNode->getChildSceneNode("my child")); //i thought this should be dynamic_cast but the compiler throws an error.. weird
```

My goal is to have "many types" of BaseNode, so I won't have to rewrite its parent/children functionality every time.

Any idea how I can do this better?

Comment: You have a base class without a single virtual function (not even a destructor). This is totally wrong, and with a high probability entails **undefined behaviour** in your program. You need to read up on the meaning of the words **object oriented**, how they are related to **polymorphism** and **inheritance**, and how these notions are implemented in C++ with virtual functions.

Comment: @n.m. and that's also his reason why the `dynamic_cast` gave him errors - @Pilpel you should be using `static_cast` to upcast nodes that you know are of a certain specialisation (`dynamic cast` for those where you cannot be sure) - `reinterpret_cast` will break your code once you're using virtual functions.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. This still doesn't answer my question though

Comment: @BeyelerStudios No he should **NOT** use **ANY** casts.

Comment: @n.m. **iff** you force every operation on every type in your scene graph yes

Comment: You are asking "Any idea how I can do this better?" What kind of answer do you want? A piece of code? It won't help you one bit if you are not familiar with the underlying notions.

Comment: I want a normal answer. I do understand these concepts, trust me. Even though I added the virtual keyword to the BaseNode functions, I still have to explicitly cast BaseNode* to SceneNode*.

Comment: Also, I don't see why I have to call these functions virtual at all. I'm not expecting a polymorphic behavior at all. I just want inheritance. (I'm not going to override the base class functions)

Comment: "I'm not expecting a polymorphic behavior at all. I just want inheritance". Wut all due respect, I don't think you understand these concepts well. The simple fact that you had no virtual destructors indicates that you have zero experience in actually using them. Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Why are you being such a schmuck? Do I really have zero experience in c++ because I didn't add virtual to a destructor in an example code? Go away

Comment: "Why are you being such a schmuck?" I get a spiritual satisfaction from it. "Do I really have zero experience in c++ because I didn't add virtual to a destructor in an example code?" Yes, actually. Zero experience in OO programming in C++ to be precise. "compiler throws an error.. weird". The compiler throws you an error because you didn't have a virtual destructor in your *real* code. Sorry.

Comment: Like I said before, I added virtuals and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Not specifying *which* error you are getting is actually against the rules here, so please add this information. Meanwhile, for your perusal, [one](http://ideone.com/voY2VL) and [two](http://ideone.com/7l06lV). As you can see, adding `virtual` actually eliminates the error. Unless you are having some other error, which I cannot divine out of your example code.

Comment: You said before I should not use any casts at all. Doesn't it include dynamic_cast? Also, I specified the error in Leroy's answer.

Comment: That's right, a proper OO design should not need any  `dynamic_cast`s. Though sometimes using it seems unavodable, each such case signifies a deficiency in the design. But one should at least strive for a clean design.

Comment: Okay. So now we go back to my first question. Is there a different approach to avoid using dynamic casts all the time? Leroy suggested templates. Anything else comes to your mind?

Comment: Based on your example code, I'd say ditch containers of BaseNode and use containers of SceneNode throughout. But let's assume you have other derived classes of BaseNode. The design heavily depends on the following question. Do they have anything in common except having children and transformation matrices? Is `attachRenderMeshData` is a part of some global operation that is implemented differently for other types of nodes? If there's not much in common, you probably can just put different types of nodes into separate containers as it makes little sense to keep them together.

Comment: IOW if most of your program is structured like "traverse the scene graph and do something with each node" (maybe different things for different types of nodes) then you can get rid of dynamic casts by using a virtual function for each "something". OTOH if most of your program is like "get a specific node, or all nodes of a certain type, and do something with them" then it is unclear why you have all the nodes in one container. Given that the types are practically unrelated, perhaps you should have a separate container for each type. (This is not an object-oriented design).

Comment: You may also find that the *visitor pattern* works well in your case. I cannot tell for sure because I don't know the details of your program. Some implementations of visitor do use casts, but there are not many of them and they are well encapsulated. IIRC it should be a single dynamic_cast in the entire design (templated, so it works for all of your types). If using visitor, you do keep all the nodes in one container.

Comment: I want to have two types of nodes. SceneNode and BoneNode. To answer your question, BoneNode and SceneNode won't have anything in common except what BaseNode has. The reason I made a base BaseNode class is because it felt wrong to write the parent/child relationships, node names, and transformation matrices two times.

Comment: It could be that your node types do have more in common than you've thought. It could also be that you are better off using containment rather than inheritance. You have names like findFirstSceneNode, presumably also findFirstBoneNode. Isn't it already expressing parent/child relationship twice?

Comment: No they're actually supposed to be named findFirstBaseNode() etc, and they operate on the vector of BaseNodes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use templates for your `BaseNode` class?

That way you can have common code between different types of BaseNode.

For example, to make a  `SceneNode`, you could do `BaseNode<SceneNode>`.

[An example on C++ class templates.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates)

---

If `SceneNode` inherits `BaseNode` you can simply assign `SceneNode` to a  `BaseNode*` type without a cast. You probably also need to call the base class's constructor as well.

```
class SceneNode : public BaseNode {
public:
    SceneNode() : BaseNode("foo") {}
};
```

From that, if you call `s = new SceneNode`, you should be able to assign s to a collection of `BaseNode*` without cast.

Comment: This makes my code look more clumsy... Is there a different solution?

Comment: Try storing your children as the `BaseNode` type so that you don't have to do `reinterpret_cast`.  If all types inherit `BaseNode`, then a pointer to `SceneNode` can be held in an array (or collection) of type `BaseNode*`.

Comment: You mean std::vector<BaseNode> instead of std::vector<BaseNode*>? If so, I don't like it. I much prefer storing pointers in vectors to avoid copying all the data members of the object when the vector reallocates.

Comment: No, I mean like `std::vector<BaseNode*>`

Comment: You don't need to `reinterpret_cast` to assign to a base pointer from an inherited type.

Comment: I get this error when I don't use a cast: a value of type `"BasePoint*" cannot be used to initliaze an entity of type "SceneNode*"`

Comment: I'm actually trying to cast BaseNode* to SceneNode*, not the opposite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88393/discussion-between-leroy-and-pilpel).